# Problema al visualizar el código en CodeSanbox

Tags: javascript

mi problema tiene que ver con la plataforma CodeSanbox, básicamente para quien no la conozca es una plataforma de edición de código online, el caso es que me piden su uso en distintas pruebas técnicas en las que al compartir un link pueden ver el código que he realizado.

Mi problema es que al compartir este código a no ser que la persona en cuestión sea invitada directamente por mi a ese proyecto, no puede ver el código, solo sale el código por defecto. Se que esto es un fallo ya que otras personas me han compartido sus Sanbox y sin estar registrado ni estar invitado puedo ver su código sin problema, alguien sabe que puedo estar haciendo mal?

He probado a enviárselo a distintas personas, probar tanto con una cuenta de otras personas en la plataforma, sin registrar, en otros buscadores, y solo pueden ver mi codigo si los invito directamente.

Comment: La respuesta a esta pregunta es sencilla. Contacta con CodeSandbox para que te ayuden a solucionarla. [En >> header >> support >> contact](https://codesandbox.io)

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.